# label element multiple inner span text truncation

Tags: html, css, sass, spectre.css

### Is it possible to *truncate one specific* inner `span` of a `label`, that contains *multiple* `span` elements, so that the `label` in total does *not overflow* into the next line?

---

I have prepared a **JSFiddle** for it on https://jsfiddle.net/keltik/k18892xe/3/, but for completeness I will also supply a part of the HTML/CSS here:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- First Spectre Accordion -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="accordion">
          <input id="accordion-1" name="accordion-radio" type="checkbox" hidden="">
          <label class="accordion-header c-hand" for="accordion-1">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
              <span class="headline">some headline that needs to be truncated1, so that everything in the parent 'label' element remains in one line</span>
              <span class="spacer"></span>
              <span class="date">dont truncate me1</span>
          </label>
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <ul class="menu menu-nav">
              <li class="menu-item">Element 1</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Element 2</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Element 3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!-- more accordions, same structure -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The **CSS file** is like this, on my development machine I am using Scss though:

```
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

---

I am using the [spectre.css framework](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components.html) and it is already included in the aforementioned JSFiddle link.

I have already **tried out** these approaches, but could not get any of them working with `label`, multiple `span` elements and the specific `spectre.css` classes:

- https://scottwhittaker.net/flexbox/2017/02/05/flexbox-and-text-truncation.html
- https://westerndevs.com/css/Using-Overflow-Ellipsis-in-Inline-Flex/
- [How to use "text-overflow: ellipsis" with a label element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881293/how-to-use-text-overflow-ellipsis-with-a-label-element)

I am looking for approaches using **HTML/CSS without Javascript**, if it is possible.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: so to make clear: one line with many span and trunc only some of them ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the text in `span.headline` needs to be truncated, so that all the stuff inside `label` eats up only one line and not multiple lines, like i demonstrate in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the use of `white-space:nowrap` and flexbox like this:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0; /*This span will never shrink*/
  margin: 0 5px;
}

span.tru {
  flex-shrink: 1;/*allow this one to shrink*/
  /*Hide the overflow*/
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<label>
<span>lorem don't truncate</span>
<span class="tru"> truncate me truncate me truncate me truncate me truncate me v truncate me truncate me truncate me</span>
<span>don't truncate me</span>
</label>
```

Comment: With this every `span` takes a seperate line... not what I wanted. Could you try to take a look at my JSFiddle and try it in there, because there are other css classes involved? I am using `FireFox`.

Comment: @kiltek really ? which browser are you using .. I hope not IE .. this is tested with Chrome and FF

Comment: @kiltek i already tried there and i create a simplified version here ;) but i will post the jsfiddle one

Comment: I think it is not working, because I also use the `accordion` provided by the spectre.css framework. So it would be really nice if you just used my JSFiddle.

Comment: @kiltek here is https://jsfiddle.net/k18892xe/4/, it's the same code as here ;) simply changed the classes

Comment: You are a wizard. I will try it out and keep you informed.